# SQL formatted date time not returning time

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm using the following to get the time/date of now to be in a nice format for sql insert. The dates working fine but the times always returning 0:0:0.

```
 public static String getDateString()
        {
            DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
            String sqlFormattedDate = time.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

            return sqlFormattedDate;
        }
```

Comment: "I'm using the following to get the time/date of now to be in a nice format for sql insert." - Why are you converting it to a string at all? Just use parameterized SQL and set the parameter to the DateTime value. Avoid unnecessary string conversions.

Comment: @JonSkeet Well said. Also, the question as written now actually do not depend on asp.net or sql usage. Tom, if you have any problem related to the usage of the date in a query or other statement, you should try a new question and provide more detail on the problem. Otherwise, you may want to retag this question to remove the sql reference since as is the question is targeted to string/date formatting and nothing else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That happens, because you're using the Date, and not the DateTime:

Just leave the Date-Part and it will be working as expected.

```
public static String getDateString()
        {
            DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
            String sqlFormattedDate = time.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

            return sqlFormattedDate;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :** You are trying to get the Date and Time from the `Date` value.
`time.Date` contains only `Date` not `Time` that is why you are always getting `0:0:0` as a time.

**Solution:**  You need to call `ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")` function on `DateTime` variable `time` directly.

Try This:

```
public static String getDateString()
    {
      DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
      String sqlFormattedDate = time.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
      return sqlFormattedDate;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That is caused by your instruction.

```
String sqlFormattedDate = time.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

As you can see [here on the official Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.datetime.date%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), by using the property "Date" of the time object you are using only the date part of actual date-time value. Basically .Date is returning a "new instance" where the time part has been set to the default 00:00:00.

Just remove the ".Date" part so that the instruction looks like below and it should work:

```
String sqlFormattedDate = time.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

USe

```
String sqlFormattedDate = time.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: That's just the same thing as an anterior answer, without the explanation.